# Show that $\ker(f)\cap \ker(g)=\{0\},\;\ker(f) + \ker(g) = V $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and $f,g:V\to V$ linear transformations such that $f(f(x))=g(g(x))=0_V$ and $f(g(x))+g(f(x)) =  1_V$ $\forall x\in V$.
>
> Show that $\ker(f)\cap \ker(g)=\{0\}, \;\ker(f) + \ker(g) = V $.
>
> and that $\ker(f)=f(\ker(g)).$

I'm not sure what $1_V$ means, is that the unit vector if so, what does that mean? I know that $0_V$ is the null vector and $0$ is just $0$ but what does it ***really*** mean?

My attempt which I think is completely wrong but we see:

Let $x\in \ker(f)$ and $f(f(x)) = 0_V$ but that means $f(0)=0_V$ and that means that $\ker(f) = \{0\}$ same with $\ker(g).$ But that would mean that $\ker(f)+\ker(g)=\{0\}$ which is contradictory with the statement....

UPDATE:

Not sure if I'm right but I think that $Imf\subseteq Kerf$ since $f(f(x))=0_V$, same for $g$. Not sure if that helps neither.

Comment: Seems like you are having trouble with notation. If this comes from a textbook, there *should* be a relevant section that clarifies notation.

Comment: Probably $1_V$ denotes the identity of $V$

Comment: @Bernard In my textbook is explained that the identity of $V$ is $Id_V$ and that's why I'm asking... since it is not explained what $1_V$ is

Comment: It is the same thing as $Id_V$.

Comment: The notion of unit vector is meaningless if you don't have a norm on your vector space.

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure they say $\ker(f)$ and $\ker(g)$ rather than $\ker(fg)$ and $\ker(gf)$?

Comment: @user10354138 Definetely

Comment: You are right to be confused, because "$f(g(x))+g(f(x)) =  1_V$" makes no sense. The author means either "$f(g(x))+g(f(x)) =  x$ for all $x$" or "$f \circ g + g \circ f = 1_V$", where $1_V$ denotes the identity map $V \to V$. Of course, both of these statements mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if 
$$
x \in \ker (f)  \Rightarrow 0 = f(x) \Rightarrow f(0) = f(f(x)) = 0 \Rightarrow 0 \in \ker(f).
$$
And thus also $0 \in \ker (g)$

Assume $\exists x \in \ker (f) \cap \ker (g) \not = 0$. This then implies that

$$
f(g(x)) + g(f(x)) = f(0) + g(0) = 0 \text{       i.e contradiction}
$$

Comment: And that means that....?

Comment: That the zero element is the only element that can be contained in $\ker f \cap \ker g$ @C.Cristi

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- If $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}x\in\Ker f\cap\Ker g$, what can you deduce for $x$ from the relation $\;f\circ g+g\circ f=\mathbf 1_V$?
- From $\;f\circ f=g\circ g=0$ you can deduce that $\;\operatorname{Im}f\subseteq \Ker f$ and similarly for $g$. Deduce from these inclusions and the rank-nullity theorem a lower bound for the dimensions of $\Ker f$ and $\Ker g$.